# Common R idioms

Tags: r

What good resources are there for R idioms, in the same line as there are for Java and Python?

Comment: @dalloliogm Before ask check on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302459/what-is-a-programming-idiom

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would primarily recommend [the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).  In particular, study section 3 on vectorization, which is probably the key concept in R programming.

Beyond that, I would second Dirk's recommendation of John Chambers book.

Going a step farther: the R language is derived primarily from Scheme.  One of the best ways to deeply understand R programming (as compared to a language like Java or C) is by learning about [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).  For this, the best resource might be SICP (the "[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)", available free online) which uses Scheme.  You can find the relevant video lectures online as well: [MIT 6.001](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-001Spring-2005/CourseHome/) and [Berkeley 61a](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/sp10/).

Comment: +1 for the R Inferno -- one of the most useful R tutorials I've read, I cant' believe I forgot to mention it :)  It both teaches you R idioms and helps avoid some nasty traps.

Answer (score 6):

There is [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Main_Page) which presents many common programming tasks in different programming languages. Then there is a blog post [by Stephen Turner](http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com/2010/01/coming-to-r-from-sql-python-sas-matlab.html) that lists several ressources for programmers coming from other languages, for instance you can find slides from [Drew Conway](http://files.meetup.com/1406240/Learning%20R%20Via%20Python%20(or%20the%20other%20way%20around).pdf) who compares Python with R.

Answer (score 4):

Easy: 2200+ packages and counting on CRAN :)

Actually, jokes aside, the best description I have read was in [Chambers (2008)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387759352).

Comment: +1 It always comes back to Chambers. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very interesting question -- R is indeed full of idioms, and the situation is made even more difficult by the fact that there are many idioms for data analysis, in addition to the more general programming ones.  Combined with R's expressiveness and its penchant for violating the principle of least surprise, this often makes the learning curve a bit steeper than one would like.

Personally, I picked up most of what I know by reading help, reading various tutorials and tip collections, and occasionally looking at source code of built-in functions.  [R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html) has useful tidbits to start with.  [Revolution Computing has links](http://blog.revolution-computing.com/2010/01/the-r-rosetta-stone.html) to good resources, particularly for programmers.  Also, I found [Howard Seltman's collection of tips and links](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/RTips.html) to be useful; I would bet that links on that page would cover most useful R idioms, but I am curious to see what else is out there.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not help you on your quest to figuring out R. But back when I was getting accustomed to R, I found that matlab to R dictionaries helped quite a bit (i.e. assuming you know how to use matlab). I can't seem to find the one I used, but found this [one](http://www.math.umaine.edu/~hiebeler/comp/matlabR.pdf), which seems to illustrate things nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, I'd say the most definite resource on all details of the R language is [Hadley Wickham's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/).
Reading this, you'll get a very thorough understanding of how R works.
The book covers - among many other things - functional and object-oriented approaches to programming in R. Other chapters are devoted to the basic data structures and to performance issues in R.
Note that this really is a published, high-quality book that is freely accessible online.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [**Rchaeology: Idioms of R Programming**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rockchalk/vignettes/Rchaeology.pdf) by Paul E. Johnson, which is one of the vignettes for the [rockchalk](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rockchalk/) package.

He [says](http://pj.freefaculty.org/R/) 'it includes "deep insights" and programming advice that reflects the customs and mannerisms of the R leaders.'