# Coding principles in R - Looking for a book/web tutorial for writing complex programs in R

Tags: r, software-design

I'm an intermediately experienced R user, with a team of R developers.
However, I find that when our programs starts growing, it becomes very hard to manage and debug, and work as a team.

I am a C++ / Java / Python user, and though this seems most similar to Python of those three, I still find it hard to deduce from known Java and Python "Best Practices" unto R.

Looking for a book or tutorial discussing coding conventions, and R software engineering principles, maybe OOP stuff?

Comment: Maybe your question is more suitable for the programmers stackexchange.

Comment: You may want to look at [Google's coding guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html)
or Hadley's [devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE:

There are two more recent books that you definitely need to check out when writing packages:

[Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) from Hadley Wickham, explaining about environments and other advanced topics.

[R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) from Hadley Wickham, giving a great guide for package writing

---

There isn't one book or style guide for writing R packages; there are numerous books about R that include package writing etc, and the R internals give you a style guide as well.

[R coding standards](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#R-coding-standards) from R internals

The books that contain the most advanced information about R as a programming language are in my view the following two:

[R programming for bioinformatics](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/publications/books/r-programming-for-bioinformatics/) from Robert Gentleman

[Software for data analysis: Programming with R](http://books.google.be/books/about/Software_for_data_analysis.html?id=UXneuOIvhEAC&redir_esc=y) from John Chambers

Both books give a lot of insight in R itself and contain useful style tips. Gentleman focuses on object oriented programming (as Bioconductor is largely S4 based), and Chambers is difficult to read but a rich information mine.

Next to that, you have a lot of information on stackoverflow to get ideas:

[Coding practice in R : what are the advantages and disadvantages of different styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406873/coding-practice-in-r-what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-different-st)

[Function commenting conventions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324568/function-commenting-conventions-in-r)

[any R style guide / checker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117359/any-r-style-guide-checker)

[What is your preferred style for naming variables in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944910/what-is-your-preferred-style-for-naming-variables-in-r)

[Common R idioms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415946/common-r-idioms)

But basically you'll have to sit down with your team and agree on a standard. There's no 'best' way, so you all just have to agree on a good way you all use in order to keep the code consistent.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'll check those out.