# python: iterator from a function

Tags: python

What is an [idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302459/what-is-a-programming-idiom) way to create an infinite iterator from a function? For example

```
from itertools import islice
import random
rand_characters = to_iterator( random.randint(0,256) )
print ' '.join( islice( rand_characters, 100))
```

would produce 100 random numbers

Comment: For the above, you would use `os.urandom(100)` though wouldn't you?

Comment: @JonClements: of course, it is just an example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want an iterator which continuously yields values until you stop asking it for new ones? Simply use

```
it = iter(function, sentinel)
```

which calls `function()` for each iteration step until the result `== sentinel`.

So choose a sentinel which can never be returned by your wanted function, such as `None`, in your case.

```
rand_iter = lambda start, end: iter(random.randint(start, end), None)
rand_bytes = rand_iter(0, 256)
```

If you want to monitor some state on your machine, you could do

```
iter_mystate = iter(getstate, None)
```

which, in turn, infinitely calls `getstate()` for each iteration step.

But beware of functions returning `None` as a valid value! In this case, you should choose a sentinel which is guaranteed to be unique, maybe an object created for exactly this job:

```
iter_mystate = iter(getstate, object())
```

Comment: The easiest sentinel to use is probably just `object()`

Comment: @JonClements You are right; I just intended to avoid creating unneeded objects. But if you need it because your function legitimately returns `None`, you should indeed use `object()`.

Answer (score 8):

Every time I see `iter` with 2 arguments, I need to scratch my head an look up the documentation to figure out exactly what is going on.  Simply because of that, I would probably roll my own:

```
def call_forever(callback):
    while True:
        yield callback()
```

---

Or, as stated in the comments by Jon Clements, you could use the `itertools.repeatfunc` recipe which allows you to pass arguments to the function as well:

```
import itertools as it
def repeatfunc(func, times=None, *args):
    """
    Repeat calls to func with specified arguments.
    Example:  repeatfunc(random.random)
    """
    if times is None:
        return it.starmap(func, it.repeat(args))
    return it.starmap(func, it.repeat(args, times))
```

Although I think that the function signature `def repeatfunc(func,times=None,*args)` is a little awkward.  I'd prefer to pass a tuple as args (it seems more explicit to me, and "explicit is better than implicit"):

```
import itertools as it
def repeatfunc(func, args=(),times=None):
    """
    Repeat calls to func with specified arguments.
    Example:  repeatfunc(random.random)
    """
    if times is None:
        return it.starmap(func, it.repeat(args))
    return it.starmap(func, it.repeat(args, times))
```

which allows it to be called like:

```
repeatfunc(func,(arg1,arg2,...,argN),times=4) #repeat 4 times
repeatfunc(func,(arg1,arg2,...))                #repeat infinitely
```

instead of the vanilla version from `itertools`:

```
repeatfunc(func,4,arg1,arg2,...)    #repeat 4 times
repeatfunc(func,None,arg1,arg2,...) #repeat infinitely
```