# Python equivalent of Java's `tryLock` (idiomatic)?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, locking, nonblocking

In Java [tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) can be used as a non-blocking attempt to acquire the lock. How can the equivalent in python be achieved? (Pythonic | [idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302459/what-is-a-programming-idiom) way is preferred!)

Java tryLock:

```
ReentrantLock lock1 = new ReentrantLock()
if (lock1.tryLock(13, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) { ... }
```

Python Lock:

```
import threading
lock = Lock()
lock.acquire() # how to lock.acquire(timeout = 13) ?
```

Comment: related ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392640/how-to-implement-a-lock-with-a-timeout-in-python-2-7

Answer (score 7):

The "**try lock**" behaviour can be obtained using `threading` module's `Lock.acquire(False)` (see the [Python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire)):

```
import threading
import time

my_lock = threading.Lock()
successfully_acquired = my_lock.acquire(False)
if successfully_acquired:
    try:
        print "Successfully locked, do something"
        time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        my_lock.release()
else:
    print "already locked, exit"
```

I can't figure out a satisfactory way to use `with` here.

Answer (score 2):

Ouch, my bad!
I should have read the python [reference for Locks](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire) to begin with!

> Lock.acquire([blocking])
>
> When invoked with the *blocking* argument set to `False`, do not block.
>   If a call with *blocking* set to `True` would block, return `False`
>   immediately; otherwise, set the lock to locked and return `True`.

So I can just do something like this (or something more advanced even :P ):

```
import threading
import time

def my_trylock(lock, timeout):
    count = 0
    success = False
    while count < timeout and not success:
        success = lock.acquire(False)
        if success:
            break
        count = count + 1
        time.sleep(1) # should be a better way to do this
    return success

lock = threading.Lock()
my_trylock(lock, 13)
```