# What is the difference between loop and while true?

Tags: loops, rust

The Rust tutorial, and now [book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/looping.html) claim there is a difference between `while true` and `loop`, but that it isn't super important to understand at this stage.

> If you need an infinite loop, you may be tempted to write this:
>
> ```
> while true {
> ```
>
> However, Rust has a dedicated keyword, loop, to handle this case:
>
> ```
> loop {
> ```
>
> Rust's control-flow analysis treats this construct differently than a while true, since we know that it will always loop. The details of what that means aren't super important to understand at this stage, but in general, the more information we can give to the compiler, the better it can do with safety and code generation, so you should always prefer loop when you plan to loop infinitely.

Having done a little bit of compiler-type work, I have to wonder what possible semantic difference there is, since it would be trivial for the compiler to figure out both are an infinite loop.

So, how does the compiler treat them differently?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This was answered on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/1v9rgp/rust_has_dowhile_loops/cer0ki4). As you said, the compiler could special-case `while true`, but it doesn't. Since it doesn't, the compiler doesn't semantically infer that an undeclared variable that's set inside a `while true` loop must always be initialized if you break out of the loop, while it does for a `loop` loop:

> It also helps the compiler reason about the loops, for example
>
> ```
> let x;
> loop { x = 1; break; }
> println!("{}", x)
> ```
>
> is perfectly valid, while
>
> ```
> let x;
> while true { x = 1; break; }
> println!("{}", x);
> ```
>
> fails to compile with "use of possibly uninitialised variable" pointing to the `x` in the `println`. In the second case, the compiler is not detecting that the body of the loop will always run at least once.
>
> (Of course, we could special case the construct `while true` to act like `loop` does now. I believe this is what Java does.)

Comment: Thanks, although that begs the question: Why?

Comment: @aij Almost certainly because `while true` implies that you can extract the `true` into a variable or return it from a function, which would cause the loop to break. Not a good developer experience.

Answer (score 32):

One major difference is that `loop` can [return a value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/loop/return.html) by passing a value to `break`. `while` and `for` [will not](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1767):

```
fn main() {
    let mut counter = 0;

    let result = loop {
        counter += 1;

        if counter == 10 {
            break counter * 2;
        }
    };

    assert_eq!(result, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to say is, in terms of performance, these are likely to be identical. While Rust itself doesn't do anything special with `while true`, LLVM likely does make that optimisation. The Rust compiler tries to keep things simple by delegating optimisations to LLVM where it can.

> in general, the more information we can give to the compiler, the better it can do with safety and code generation

While certain constant expressions might get optimised away by LLVM, the semantics of the language are not altered by whether an expression is constant or not. This is good, because it helps humans reason about code better too.

Just because `true` is a simple expression, we know it's constant. And so is `true != false` and `[0; 1].len() == 1`. But what about `num_cpus::get() == 1`? I actually don't know if there are some compilation targets where that could be constant, and I shouldn't have to think about it either!

The error in [telotortium's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892351/what-is-the-difference-between-loop-and-while-true/28892433#28892433) would be more significant when combined with generated code or macros. Imagine a macro which *sometimes* results in a simple static expression like `true == true`, but *sometimes* references a variable or calls a function. Sometimes the compiler is able to ascertain that the loop runs once, but other times it just can't. In Rust right now, the error in that example will *always* be an error, no matter what code was generated for that condition. No surprises.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between loop and while true?

You could ask what is the difference between `for` and `while`? The answer will be close to: [What is a programming idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/302459/7076153)

When you write `while condition {}`, you say "while condition is true, do that", but we can see that say "while true is true, do that", is redundant. This is where `loop` comes from, it can express infinite loops very well  because we say "loop on that". We don't have any condition, this is better.

> So, how does the compiler treat them differently?

I can't answer the "how" question, but I suppose you want to know "why". It allows the compiler to know that this loop will run at least one time, like the `do {} while (condition);` from C. The compiler can use this information to produce better code or warnings. Plus, you will be certain that the loop will be executed where a `while` loop could be gone because the compiler optimize it away. The fun part is that internally Rust uses LLVM, and it looks like LLVM doesn't have a way to express infinite loop, so it produces [bugs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28728) in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR `loop` is an expression; `while true` is a statement, they have different use cases and offer flexibility and expressiveness.

The main reason is that `loop` blocks are expressions, whereas `while` blocks are statements. Differentiating the both and setting distinct rules for each case allows the compiler to make optimizations without sacrificing safety.

While `loop` and `while true` loops have the same behavior (and probably similar optimizations—the condition checking at the beginning of each `while true` loop iteration is dropped for performance), they are still bound to their Rust implementations, and cannot be used interchangeably.

For instance, we can use `loop` loops like this:

```
let mut counter = 0;
let result = loop {
    counter += 1;
    if counter == 10 {
        break counter * 2; // Return a value from the loop
    }
};
println!("The result is {}", result); // The result is 20
```

We can see that we assign the evaluation of the `loop` expression to result with no problems.

On the other hand, `while` loops are statements, and so we cannot assign them to variables, etc.

Doing the same with a `while true` loop would look like this:

```
let mut counter = 0;
let mut result = 0;
while counter < 10 {
    counter += 1;
    if counter == 10 {
        result = counter * 2; // Assign a value inside the loop
        break;
    }
};
println!("The result is {}", result); // The result is 20
```

If we tried to implement this simple algorithm using `while true` in the same way as `loop` would yield the following compiler error:

```
let mut counter = 0;
let mut result = while counter < 10 {
    counter += 1;
    if counter == 10 {
        counter * 2; // Statement, hence () is returned
        break
    }
};
println!("The result is {}", result); // `()` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
```

```
error[E0277]: `()` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src/main.rs:10:34
   |
10 |     println!("The result is {}", result); // The result is 20
   |                                  ^^^^^^ `()` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `()`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` which comes from the expansion of the macro `println` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: This is not correct. Both loops are expressions in Rust, it is just that `while` always returns `()`. And there is already an answer covering the fact that you can break with value out of `loop` but not `while`.