# What optimizations does the Rust compiler make with `loop` versus `while true`?

Tags: optimization, rust, infinite-loop

Aside from the fact that it can reason about uninitialized values set within the `loop` body, are there any other compelling reasons for `loop` to exist ?

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28892351/1233251

Comment: Thanks. But, i thought my statement: `the fact that it can reason about uninitialized values set within the loop body` already hinted that i was interested in knowing what other ways could `loop` offer more avenues for compiler optimizations.

Comment: Sure, I wouldn't call it a duplicate. But it does contain important information, including external resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than you state your intention, there is no difference. All loops are the same once normalization has happened in the compiler.

See an [example of a `loop` in the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20x%20%3D%201000%3B%0A%20%20%20%20loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20-%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20x%20%3D%3D%200%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20panic!(%22We%20ran%20out%20of%20money!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22We%20still%20have%20money%20left%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0) and [the same example with a `while true`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20x%20%3D%201000%3B%0A%20%20%20%20while%20true%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20-%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20x%20%3D%3D%200%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20panic!(%22We%20ran%20out%20of%20money!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22We%20still%20have%20money%20left%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0). The assembly generated is exactly the same. The compiler gives a warning for the `while true`-example to use `loop` instead.

Comment: Can you prove this in any way?

Comment: @Shepmaster you could compare MIR or ASM output if proof is required

Comment: @the8472 that only proves that the assembly (and presumably relevant optimizations) is the same *for a single case*, which is a pretty low bar. I could imagine wildly different code samples that compile to the same assembly even though the path to get to get there is completely different (thus having different available optimizations).

Comment: The question's title is `What optimizations does the Rust compiler make with loop versus while true?`

Comment: @Shepmaster I would think that `while(true) {}` vs. `loop{}` are sufficiently trivial and the differences localized enough that wildly different adjacent code will not be able to confuse the optimizers. Also, MIR happens before optimization AIUI

Comment: @the8472 I **think** so as well, but I cannot *prove* something by just thinking it to be true. Concretely, [the result type of `loop` differs from that of `while true`](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=193b0502f8172cf2ad7378813924ed1a&version=stable). Are there optimizations that can be made based on that piece of information? I don't know. Additionally, having two pieces of code that do the same thing in different ways often *doesn't* optimize the same way. Autovectorization is a prime example of such cases.

Comment: @the8472 *MIR happens before optimization* I'm not completely sure the connection of that and this issue, but [there are passes in the compiler that seem to indicate that there are optimization passes **on** MIR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/341f4534488a3f56b8b9e188c1f4f52ed7707389/src/librustc_driver/driver.rs#L916-L943). Anecdotally, I've also heard of people wanting to perform optimization at that level.